# Show the power series converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Show that the power series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{n(1+nx^2)}$ converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$.

How should i approach this question? Weirestrass M-test does not work for $|x|>1$ here.

Comment: I think the Weierstrass M test does work. Take a closer look at the maximum value of the general term $x/(n(1+nx^2)$.

Comment: @MarkMcClure can u help me on this?

Comment: As noted in the A by Ted Shifrin, this is not a power series in $x$. A power series in $x$ is of the form $\sum_{n\geq 0} A_nx^n$ where each $A_n$ is independent of $x.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, this is *not* a power series. Why does the Weierstrass M-test not work? Let $f_n(x)=\dfrac x{n(1+nx^2)}$ and show (by the usual calculus technique) that the maximum of $|f_n|$ occurs at $x=\pm 1/\sqrt n$. Therefore $|f_n(x)|\le \dfrac 1{2n^{3/2}}$ for all $x$. Weierstrass applies immediately.